# Wordpress Intercepting Requests To A File In Public HTML

Tags: htaccess

I have the following htaccess in the public_html

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have an external page that I want to show users from within my shared hosting wordpress install. This page has nothing to do with the rest of the wordpress site, and is called `thanksgiving.html`

I want when I go to my site

`http://www.example.com/thanksgiving` it goes to `thanksgiving.html` instead of a 404 in Wordpress telling me it can't find a page or post with that permalink. How can I modify the httaccess just so people requesting the thanksgiving page we are making aren't shown the Wordpress side of things?

Comment: Just create a subfolder 'thanksgiving/', and make the file 'index.html' in there. No need to muck around with your htaccess then :)

Comment: @TimMalone Yep that's what I've done in the meantime.

Comment: Since that's probably the best answer to your question, perhaps you could [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/244214/edit) your question to include why that's not a suitable long-term solution for you?